# React Router Issue: React render two components in the same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm having issues with my project, actually i'm trying to handle a 404 page when the user enters different url outside of the Routes in my App, but using my knowledge of React and react-router only needs to put the last route has no path and **exact path** wrapped by a **Switch** from react-router but not work well, the home page is rendering the **Home** and the **NotFound** components at same time.

I've tried to remove Container component inside the Router but that makes that all of the components after MenuBar disappears.

I've tried to put path='*' in the last Route having 2 components rendered in the same page.

A picture of what i'm talking about:
[2 components at same time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skgdj.jpg)

My project have 3 principal files:

1.- Index.js :

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import ApolloProvider from './ApolloProvider';

import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import 'animate.css/animate.min.css';
import './App.css';

ReactDOM.render(ApolloProvider, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

2.- ApolloProvider.js (using Apollo with GraphQL) :

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql'
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
);
```

3.- And finally App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import MenuBar from './Components/MenuBar';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Login from './Pages/Login';
import Register from './Pages/Register';
import NotFound from './Pages/404';

const App = props => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Container>
                <MenuBar />
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Container>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default App;
```

I only need to render Home component when the user visits '/' but it's weird how react-router is rendering two components at same time, please le me know if you find where i'm wrong or a solution for that, i'll being posting updates if i find a solution or whatever.

Thanks in advance mates!.

Comment: are `Home` and `NotFound` rendered simultaneously?

Comment: The switch needs to be around the Route components, not around container. So hierarchy is Router => Container => [MenuBar, Switch => Route[]]

Comment: yes @skyboyer, if you see the attached image the ```NotFound``` component it's rendered at the same time as ```home/login/register``` components.

Comment: I don't see attached image, guess mobile version doesn't render images. as Hugo Dozois said, ordering matters. `Switch` affects only immediate children regardless if that are `Route` or anything else(and there is just single one immediate child - `Container`)

Comment: perfect! all works fine, i'm going crazy with this simple hierarchy issue, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @skyboyer and @Hugo Dozois the issue was fixed, this is the updated `App.js` for future references:

```
const App = props => (
    <Router>
        <Container>
            <MenuBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
        </Container>
    </Router>
);
```

Best Regards!